# Enviromental impact of nvidia jetson agx xavier

Tags: graphics-card

Good day.

I currently work on the LCA of a drone which control the cleanliness of landing runway.
It use a Nvidia Jetson AGX Xavier to analyse video of the runway in real time through deep learning, but I struggle to find any data on enviromental cost (gas emission, rare material, electricity) of production and recycling, as well as electric consumption.

On their website, Nvidia indicates that it has several consumption mode (10 W, 15 W and 30 W) but is their any link between consumption and the weigh of the running program ?

I contacted Nvidia support but never recieved any answer.

More globally, I search for data on environmental impact of graphics cards and CPU production.

Thanks a lot to any who could help me.